# How can I split a string into two float numbers in Javascript？

Tags: javascript, computer-science

```
function xyDistance(from,to){
var s=from.split(",");
var x1=parseFloat(s[0]);
 var y1=parseFloat(s[1]);


 var dt = Math.sqrt( (x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2);
 return dt;
}
```

I will enter the two coordinates as a string. I have split them, but I don't know how to separate the X and Y coordinates of two points.The photo shows the input value and expected output value.
[image]

Comment: Just... `.split` them again with `,`?

Answer (score 1):

For each `from`, `to`, you just have to split it and parseInt

```js
function xyDistance(from, to) {
  var [x1, y1] = from.split(",").map(axis => parseInt(axis, 10));
  var [x2, y2] = to.split(",").map(axis => parseInt(axis, 10));


  var dt = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2);
  return dt;
}

console.log(xyDistance('1,1', '0,0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your algorithm is supposed to be doing, but to get the x,y coords of both, just do a split on each argument. And, fyi, all numbers in JavaScript are floating point (whole numbers just aren't displayed with decimals unless you format them to).

```js
function xyDistance(from,to){
  var f = from.split(",");
  var x1 = parseFloat(f[0]);
  var y1 = parseFloat(f[1]);
  
  var t = to.split(",");
  var x2 = parseFloat(t[0]);
  var y2 = parseFloat(t[1]);  
    
  console.log("from x,y are: " + x1 + ", " + y1);
  console.log("to x,y are: " + x2 + ", " + y2);  
}

xyDistance("1,1","0,0");
xyDistance("1,1","-1,-1");
```

Comment: Calculate the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

Answer (score 0):

```js
function xyDistance(from,to){
const [x1, y1] = from.split(",");
const [x2, y2] = to.split(",");
const dt = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2);
return dt;
}

console.log(xyDistance("2,1", "0,1"))
```

try above code, no need to parse float

Answer (score 0):

You could split the values and take the delta of same index as value for [`Math.hypot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot).

```js
function xyDistance(from, to) {
    const
        f = from.split(',');
        t = to.split(',');

    return Math.hypot(f[0] - t[0], f[1] - t[1]);
}

console.log(xyDistance("1,1", "0,0"));
console.log(xyDistance("1,1", "-1,-1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work

```
function xyDistance(from,to){
var f=from.split(",");
var fx=parseFloat(f[0]);
var fy=parseFloat(f[1]);

var t=to.split(",");
var tx=parseFloat(t[0]);
var ty=parseFloat(t[1]);


 var dt = Math.sqrt( (fx-tx)**2+(fy-ty)**2);
 return dt;
}
```